# Design an extensible permissions model in database

Tags: design, design-patterns, database

I’m trying to model a system with Users, Permissions and Products. The main goal is to have a way of checking if a User has a specific Permission in order to allow or deny other system operations.

So Users will have a list of Permissions and this Permissions will be given to the User when the User buys a specific Product.

This way the Users will have Permissions but the Products must have something like a “template” of the Permission that the User that buys the product will get.

This structure could be simplified to users having products and products having permissions but one of the requirements is to have the possibility of assigning a specific permission to a specific user without needing a product. And also each permission has its own context so, each permission has its own relation with a user and some other variables that mutate over time and can change the permission validity.

I’m trying to map this domain to a database structure but I’m stuck with the relation between permissions and products.

Thanks

Comment: A user buys many products. A product has many permissions. A user has many permissions through the products they buy.

Comment: I wrote that option but saying that this is not possible because the permissions should be also manageable per user without the need of having a product

Comment: You are conflating database design with software design. If you are looking for a proper relational database schema, this has nothing to do with code. If you are looking for a model in code, that has nothing to do with the database. The question seems to be about the database, so remove at least the "object-oriented-design" tag.

Comment: @RobertBräutigam: if an object oriented language is using a relational database, then both apply. The challenge is adapting the object oriented model to the relational database. I think tackling both in one question is too broad. Focus on database first, then the OO model.

Comment: Would you ever need to revoke a permission that was given to the user from a purchase?

Comment: If the permissions associated with a product change, do you want all permissions for user who purchased that product to reflect that change?

Comment: The revoke is not necessary. When the product change, only new users should get the new permissions

Comment: (1) You're talking about "only new permissions" when a product "changes"; which implies that permissions get revoked when on product update. How else are you going to distinguish permissions that were given before/after said update to the product? (2) Just because you're using an OOP language does not mean that the OOP tag is relevant - the question is whether the question you're asking is rooted in OOP, which for your case it isn't. (3) If you need to be able to set a user's permissions without the need of having a product; how will you define to which products the permissions apply?

Answer (score 3):

I'm under 50 points so I cannot comment, but I can answer.
If I understood alright, you have:

A Product has permissions associated to it.
A Person that buys a product will have all the permissions associated to that product.
A Person may have another permissions besides the permissions "automatically" given by buying a product.

So lets say:
ProductA has permissions PerA1 and PerA2.
ProductB has permissions PerB1 and PerB2.

Now lets say a *UserA* buys the product *ProductA*. Then this person will have permissions: *PerA1* and *PerA2*.
And because of some reason,the system wants to assign *UserA* also de permission PerB1 (with no need of buying ProductB). So at the end:

UserA has PerA1, PerA2 and PerB1.

Is this right?
If this is the case, You will have 3 tables for users, products and permissions. And you also need two more tables:

*) One for associating Users with Permissions i.e ***UserPermission*** with fields: ID, UserID, PermissionID
*) Another one for associating Products with Permissions i.e ***ProductPermission*** with fields: ID, ProductID, PermissionID

Then, when you say:
And also each permission has its own context so, each permission has its own relation with a user and some other variables that mutate over time and can change the permission validity.

It is not very clear to me. But I suppose you may add this "context" (whatever it is) in the relationship between Users and Permissions i.e in the Table *UserPermission*